# Actual cost of transpose = GL_TRUE in glUniformMatrix* functions

Tags: opengl

Functions `glUniformMatrix*` has a transpose parameter "specifying whether to transpose the matrix as the values are loaded into the uniform variable." See [glUniform man page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml).

**Is there any performance cost between `glUniformMatrix4fv(-, -, GL_FALSE, -)` and `glUniformMatrix4fv(-, -, GL_TRUE, -)`**

Comment: Why don't you profile it and see? Also, the answer is likely to vary with card vendor and OS vendor, regardless.

Comment: My question is obviously theoretical. Profiling could be useful for one context but for another one, the results could be completely different. Understanding what's going on under the hood is important to me. Profiling is clearly not understanding...

Comment: Even though that profiling wouldn't make you understand what happens behind the screen. It would still give a clear picture if there is any cost at all using `GL_TRUE` than `GL_FALSE` for `glUniformMatrix*`

Comment: You can't know what's going on under the hood and you can't be guaranteed it will remain the same over subsequent driver updates. Each vendor writes their drivers differently for each OS. Also, the point of hardware abstraction layers like OpenGL is specifically so that clients of those abstractions won't have to know what's going on under the hood so that it can be changed at any time without affecting the clients.

Comment: You can easily avoid transposing matrices if you reverse the order of matrix multiplication in your shader. Transposing is actually pretty cheap, it is taking the inverse that is often much more expensive (though in some special cases the two operations are the same).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: my concern is that I would like to know if the matrix is "really" transposed. I would think it is just done while copying it so it should have no impact. Not sure though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's going on under the hood? It depends.

You're copying 16 floats, 64 bytes of memory, from the source to a GPU destination. If transpose is true, those 16 floats get re-arranged as part of the copy. There's no calculation involved like there is for an inverse matrix, just swapping the rows and columns.

On an x86 the transpose needs 4 loads into SSE registers, 4 instructions to re-arrange, and then 4 stores back to memory.

What's the performance cost? Disclaimer: I am not a hardware engineer, so these are back of the envelope answers.

If the CPU and GPU share memory, like Intel integrated, AMD Fusion, or Xbox 360, then a straight memory to memory copy has become load - transpose - store. But if the matrix is something you've just calculated, it's probably in cache already so the loads are almost free. And the SSE register to register instructions are just nanoseconds.

If the CPU sends data to the GPU on a card over PCI-X, the time to set up and finish the bus transfer would take longer than the tranpose or the copy for just 64 bytes. But I would like to think that a smart graphics driver is aware of this and batches up glUniform calls into larger chunks. So again, the extra overhead is just a few extra instructions.

All in all, I'd say the performance cost won't be detectable until you get down to microsecond accuracy. And if you are going that low level, there's almost certainly much worse things happening that you should worry about.

Comment: Are you sure that it is first copied, then transposed? I would imagine it is just copied in "transposed order". But if the cost is negligible it does not really matter.